# Prove using natural deduction that $(R \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q))\vdash (Q\rightarrow P) \lor (P \rightarrow Q)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I ran into some trouble proving the following:

$(R \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q))\vdash (Q\rightarrow P) \lor (P \rightarrow Q)$

My approach thus far:

Honestly I'm really stuck. So basically my hypothesis requires this $R$, hence the first thing that came to my mind is the Law of Excluded Middle. Using $R$ is trivial. The problem comes with $\neg R$. I can't seem to proceed from there.

Any help or insights is deeply appreciated.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: This isn't strictly a duplicate. But the OP should perhaps have waited for an answer to their similar question to see if the answer to that would give a  clue how to answer this (which it does!). Otherwise this smacks of just coming to get other people to do all one's homework thinking!

Comment: @PeterSmith: maybe, but that doesn't make it a duplicate. Maybe the OP needs to learn more about how to use MSE properly, but that is no justification for closing a question for a blatantly incorrect reason. That the vote to close was endorsed by 5 users appals me.

Comment: @PeterSmith: also a better clue to this question is to point out that the RHS of the sequent here is provable without using the LHS.

Comment: Hint: $P\to (Q\to P)$ and $\lnot P\to(P\to Q)$ are provable tautologies , so do that, and use LEM as $P\lor\lnot P$ to eliminate the disjunction.

Answer (score 0):

Since the conclusion $(Q→P)∨(P→Q)$ is a tautology, one does not need the premise to prove the conclusion. One can prove this using the Law of the Excluded Middle (LEM) in the following manner:

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/

Answer (score -1):

You can use the exportation law

$ ( R \to (P \to Q)) \Leftrightarrow (( R \land P ) \to Q) $

to reduce this question to 
[prove using natural deduction $((P \land Q) \rightarrow R) \vdash (P \rightarrow R) \lor (Q\rightarrow R)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645591/prove-using-natural-deduction-p-land-q-rightarrow-r-vdash-p-rightarrow?lq=1)

Which you have already asked.

Comment: There is no $R$ on the RHS of the sequent in this question, so it isn't the same as the linked question.

Comment: Actually $\vdash (Q \to P) \lor (P \to Q)$ is provable without any hypothesis, so the linked question is irrelevant.